# printf ignores single backslash '\'

Tags: c, string, printf

I have this code :

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
int i;
printf("%d%s",argc,argv[1]);
return 0;
}
```

If I run this code as `a.out a\=b=`.I am using `C-shell`

Its output is "`a=b=`" is there any way that its output can be changed to "`a\=b=`".

Comment: You changed the question substantially. Before it was a question about strings in C, now it is a question how to enter a string on the command line of a shell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update for edited question**:

Enclose your command line argument in quotes:

```
  $ a.out "a\=b="
```

The quotes prevent the shell from interpreting the command line argument in any way, so just this string is passed to your program. I use the `csh`/`bash` ..works with both.

Alternatively, you can "escape" the `\` with another one and skip the double quotes:

```
  $ a.out a\\=b=
```

---

**Previous answer to original question**:

Yes, use two `\`:

```
char a[]="a\\=b=";
```

outputs:

```
a\=b=
```

**Explanation**:

`\` is an escape character used to indicate a special character sequence, so for instance `\t` indicates a tab. If you want to actually print `\t`, you need to "escape" this `\` with another `\`. See this example and output:

```
printf("\t-->Hi\n");    /* print regular tab via \t                        */
printf("\\t-->Hi\n");   /* want to print "\t", not tab  ..so we use two \\ */
```

which results in:

```
    -->Hi
\t-->Hi
```

This is *not* unique to the `printf()` function, nor really to C, may languages use the backslash to indicate "escape sequences" in strings.

Comment: how can that be done? can i write a code that can convert `"a\=b="` to `"a\\=b="`

Comment: @nav_jan Not sure I understand your question -- even though your put two back-slashes, printf will interpret it correctly and generate one on output.

Answer (score 7):

`printf()` is not ignoring your single backslash, it's the way C strings are parsed. A backslash is an *escape* character to indicate some character that is not easily entered in a string, for example a newline (`\n`) or embedded quote (`\"`). Consequently, to include a backslash you must include *two* backslashes (`\\`).  This is for all strings, and not related to `printf()`.

Comment: how can that be done? can i write a code that can convert `"a\=b="` to `"a\\=b="`

Comment: As in you have it many places and want to change them? Sounds like a job for search+replace or a regex.

Comment: no i am giving the string from command line `a.out a\=b=` and i want to print argv[1].

Comment: A string you enter from your shell won't be interpreted by C in this way it all. However, it *may* be interpreted by your *shell*. To know for sure, we'll need to know which shell you're using, though.

Comment: c-shell will indeed interpret the backslash away unless you quote or escape it, any one of `a\\=b` or `"a\=b"` or `'a\=b'` ought to work.

Answer (score 1):

The `\` is the escape character in strings in C. You use it to access special character such as newline (`\n`). If you want to access the `\` as a character, you need too escape it: `\\`.

Comment: how can that be done? can i write a code that can convert `"a\=b="` to `"a\\=b="`

Comment: @nav_jan No, just type  `\\ `  if you want to display `\ `.

Comment: what if when i am giving the string from command line `a.out a\=b=` and i want to print argv[1]

Answer (score 0):

\\ is what is read as \ in C

\ is the only character used inside a char or string in C to denote some other character or string of characters. That's what is meant by the name "escape" character.

Because it's used in this way, it was necessary to include the backslash itself one of the symbols indictable by such a sequence.

Some other sequences are: 
\n    new line
\t    tab
\v    vertical tab
\a    alert bell sound